# The convergence of re-scaled function with mollification

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $u\in L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb R^N)$. Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be open bounded. Let $\eta_\epsilon$ be the standard mollification function and we define $u_\epsilon:=u\ast \eta_\epsilon$. It is well known that $u_\epsilon\to u$ in $L^p(\Omega)$.

Now, let $B$ be the unit ball in $\mathbb R^N$ centered at the origin, and we define 
$$
\tilde u_\epsilon(x):=u_\epsilon\left((1+\epsilon)x\right).
$$

My question, how may I prove that $\tilde u_\epsilon\to u_\epsilon$ in $L^p(B)$? I tried to use LDCT but I can't find the dominated function...

Comment: you mean $\tilde{u}_\epsilon \to u$. show that the operator $T_\epsilon : u(x) \to u((1+\epsilon)x)$ is bounded in $L^p(B)$, so if $u_\epsilon \to u$ then $T_\epsilon u_\epsilon \to u$, and the dominated convergence is by $\max_{\|v\|=1} \|T_\epsilon(v)\|$

Comment: @user1952009 So $\{T_\epsilon\}$ is actually a family of operators, right ?

Comment: @Svetoslav yes $T_\epsilon : L^p (\Bbb {R}^n) \to L^p (\Bbb {R}^n), \quad f \mapsto ( x\mapsto f ((1+\epsilon)x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the hint in the comment, define
$$
L^p (\Bbb {R}^n) \to L^p (\Bbb {R}^n), f \mapsto ( x\mapsto f ((1+\epsilon)x)
$$
and show (exercise) that there is $C>0$ with 
$$
\|T_\epsilon f \|_p \leq C \cdot \|f\|_p \quad \quad (\ast)
$$
for all $\epsilon \leq 1$ and all $ f \in L^p (\Bbb {R}^n)$.

Now, I will assume $u \in L^p (\Bbb {R}^n)$ instead of $L_{\rm loc}^p $. The modification for that case is not hard. We have
$$
\|\tilde {u_\epsilon} - u\|_p = \|(T_\epsilon u_\epsilon ) -u\|_p \leq \|T_\epsilon (\eta_\epsilon \ast u) -T_\epsilon u\|_p + \| T_\epsilon u - u\|_p \leq C \|u_\epsilon - u\|_p + \|T_\epsilon u - u\| \to 0
$$
as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Here, the last step used
$$
T_\epsilon u \to u
$$
in $L^p $. This is not hard to see for $u \in C_c $ and follows for general $u $ by approximation (using $(\ast) $ from above).